# Python list comprehension for joining lists (flattened)

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, mongoengine

So I'm currently working with mongoengine, although anything with properties will have the same behavior.

I have a list called **collections**. Technically it's a mongoengine QuerySet, which is an iterable, but it has virtually all the same behaviors as a list.

Each element collections is an object, with a property called **addons** which is also a list.

I want to create a flat list of all the addons. Currently doing this produces the desired result

```
addons = []
for col in collections:
    addons+=col.addons
```

But when I try this, which I assume is the equivalent list comprehension, I get a list of lists (it essentially *appends* each list together instead of *adding* them)

```
addons = [col.addons for col in collections]
```

I've been reading about nested list comprehensions and even using itertools but haven't been able to figure out how to get either to work properly

Comment: It's not the same. That's a list of lists. This is a list of objects that have a list as one of their properties, meaning I can't simply do a nesting of for loops

Comment: Sure you could: `[item for col in collections for item in col.addons]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [itertools.chain.from_iterable](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) like so:

```
from itertools import chain
addons = list(chain.from_iterable(col.addons for col in collections))
```

Available on Python >= 2.6. In the past, it's been quite fast. Faster even than the double list comprehension.

Comment: Awesome! That did the trick and was, indeed, super fast. Thanks!

Comment: @JaredJoke you can map it either way. The itertools module provides an imap function so you could do list(chain.from_iterable(imap(processing_func, col.addons) for col in collections)))

Answer (score 1):

you need a double list comprehension, like:

```
addons = [item for item in col.addons for col in collections]
```

Comment: I tried that and got an error.
UnboundLocalError: 
local variable 'col' referenced before assignment

Comment: Should probably be `[item for col in collections for item in col.addons]`. `collections` is a poor name for a variable btw, clashes with the `collections` module name.